# How to exclude multiple folders in PowerShell in Get-ChildItem to look and delete duplicated files

Tags: powershell, where-clause, get-childitem

I am trying to search and delete duplicate files in a root Directory, but I don't want the script look for some subdirectorys.

My code is this but it fails when I run it:

```
$srcDir = "rootDir"
$thiscarpetsExclude = "rootDir/subDir1","rootDir/subDir1/childsubDir1","rootDir/subDir2","rootDir/subDir3"...

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse | where FullName -NotLike $thiscarpetsExclude* | 
  Group -Property Length |  
  where { $_.Count -gt 1 } | select -ExpandProperty Group | 
  Group -Property Extension | where {$_.count -gt 1} |
  select -ExpandProperty Group |
  Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |  
  Group -Property Hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | 
  foreach { $_.Group | select Path, Hash } |
  Out-GridView -Title "Select the file(s) to remove" -PassThru |
  Remove-Item -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code seem to be the exclusion part, `$thiscarpetsExclude*` is not a valid exclusion pattern as you would be concatenating all elements in your exclusion array with a space and then concatenating that string with a `*` at the end:

```
$thiscarpetsExclude = @(
    'rootDir/subDir1'
    'rootDir/subDir1/childsubDir1'
    'rootDir/subDir2'
    'rootDir/subDir3'
)

& {param($i) $i } $thiscarpetsExclude*

# Outputs:
# rootDir/subDir1 rootDir/subDir1/childsubDir1 rootDir/subDir2 rootDir/subDir3*
```

What you can do instead is use [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) with [`StartsWith(String, StringComparison)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-8.0#system-string-startswith(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) in your delegate and then negating that evaluation:

```bash
$exclude = [string[]]@(
    'rootDir/subDir1'
    'rootDir/subDir1/childsubDir1'
    'rootDir/subDir2'
    'rootDir/subDir3'
)

$delegate = [System.Func[string, bool]] {
    $_.FullName.StartsWith($args[0], [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Any($exclude, $delegate) } |
    # rest of the code here...
```

Another way to do it is with a regex pattern and using `-NotMatch` instead:

```
$exclude = [string[]]@(
    'rootDir/subDir1'
    'rootDir/subDir1/childsubDir1'
    'rootDir/subDir2'
    'rootDir/subDir3'
)

$excludePattern = '^(?:{0})' -f ($exclude.ForEach{ [regex]::Escape($_) } -join '|')

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object FullName -NotMatch $excludePattern |
    # rest of the code here...
```